# I loop the teams from a database and get the result(example) are: Team Alfa - Team Bravo Team Charlie - Team Delta

Tags: java

Then I want to select the teams individually like:
West Ham United 
Orlando Pirates 
Kaizer Chiefs 
Everton...
I decided to use split to add them on an Array so I can use their index number to select them. I get the first team and last team correctly but the teams in between I get something like :
println(choose_team[3]);
Manchester United  Arsenal but I want them individually. Please see the code! Any solutions?

String answer = "";

// the below string games is the teams example I'm going to extract and store.

```
    String games = "West Ham United - Orlando Pirates Kaizer Chiefs - Everton  Liverpool - Manchester United Arsenal - Real Madrid";

    // below I want to split and store as an array

    String[] numbers = games.split("-");  

    System.out.println("splited String variable after loop:");

    for(String ans : numbers){ 

    System.out.println(ans); 

        answer += ans + "-"; } 

        answer = answer.substring(0,answer.length()-1); 

    String[] choose_team = answer.split("-");


      System.out.println("the - sign is re-instated:" + "\n" + answer);

    //  I want to get the teams individually and a print statement is just showing what I want but I'm going to use the teams somewhere else in a code.

      System.out.println("splited string with index 4: " + "\n" + choose_team[0]);

   System.out.println("splited string with index 0: " + "\n" + choose_team[4]);

    System.out.println("splited string with index 1: " + "\n" + choose_team[1]);

    System.out.println("splited string with index 2: " + "\n" + choose_team[2]);
```

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: Check my output in detail

Comment: //output
  West Ham United
  Orlando Pirates Kaizer Chiefs
  Everton Liverpool 
  Manchester United Arsenal
  Real Madrid
  
  //output
  West Ham United - Orlando Pirates Kaizer Chiefs - Everton Liverpool - Manchester United Arsenal - Real Madrid
  
    //output
    West Ham United                         
   //output
    Real Madrid
    
     //output
     Orlando Pirates Kaizer Chiefs
     
     //output
     Everton Liverpool

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question i think this can help

```
 final String games = "Team Alfa - Team Bravo Team Charlie - Team Delta Team Echo - Team Foxtrot Team Golf - Team Hotel";
    final String[] numbers = games.split("(?=Team)");
    final List teams = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("splited String variable after loop:");

    for (String ans : numbers) {
        ans = ans.replaceAll("[-+^]*", "");
        System.out.println(ans);
        teams.add(ans);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Team No. " + i + " " + teams.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: "(?=Team)" This can help if all the teams from data base starts with Team but  the String games = "Team Alfa - Team Bravo Team Charlie - Team Delta Team Echo - Team Foxtrot Team Golf - Team Hotel"  is just an example. Here is a realistic teams below:

Comment: String games = "Manchester United  - Arsenal  Everton -  Manchester City  Liverpool  - Real Madrid";

Comment: is delimiter will alwayes be (-) you can try 
       ' final String[] numbers = games.split("(?=Team)|-");'
 and before adding them use
   
 
        '    if (!ans.equals(" ") && ans != null) {
                teams.add(ans);
            }
'